# Configure a UNIX server to send its logs to a remote syslog server?

Tags: unix, logging, remote, syslogd, syslog

Is it possible?

If so, how is it done exactly? The syslog.conf file doesn't help too much.

Comment: Have you done any research already? Sending logging entries to a remote server is one of the core capabilities of `syslogd`. Here's just one guide I quickly dug up: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Setting-Up-a-Central-Syslog-Server-44063.shtml

Comment: @OliverSalzburg For completeness here is a guide describing the problems in the syslog "plain tcp format", an interesting read: http://blog.gerhards.net/2008/04/on-unreliability-of-plain-tcp-syslog.html

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg

According to my understanding, syslogd is the daemon running the local logging.

Comment: One might want to have a look at RELP, which addresses some of the reliability issues that may (rarely) pop up with rsyslogd. http://wiki.chilblain.net/dokuwiki/doku.php/howto:reliable_remote_logging_with_relp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you can use rsyslog.

There is a good online manual for doing this: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_reliable_forwarding.html

And the general rsyslog doc is: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html

Comment: I use rsyslog for this exact purpose.

Comment: @mattdm could you explain why using rsyslog is *plain wrong*? It does work for me and others (customers): I have been using it in various professional environments. But I guess you have some arguments and I would be curious to here them and discuss further with you. For this purpose I invite you to use the chat feature. We could then put a summary here once we discussed it.

Comment: @mattdm Ho, OK understood. I did not see that the words carried such strong "narrow" emphasis. I will update the sentence then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following line at the end of /etc/rsyslog.conf

for udp

> *.* @remoteserverip

for tcp

> *.* @@remoteserverip